Unable to create vmfs datastore an virtual machine at the same time (in parallel)
currently I am trying to completely automate a VMware virtualization environment. This includes multiple ESXi server and one central vCenter to manage everything. Therefore I want to deploy the following this in order:

Distributed Port Group
vSphere Folder
VMFS Datastore
Creation of Virtual machines

Therefore I wrote a dedicated module for the creation of all VM's according to an separate list in json.
My thought is, to deploy everything in one step. I already implemented the 'depends_on' dependencies to every resource which depends on the other resources but some I always get the error "there must be at least one disk specified".
This are my related files:
datasources.tf:
########### General ###########
data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = "DATACENTER"
}

########### Network ###########
data "vsphere_distributed_virtual_switch" "vds" {
  name          = var.project_vds
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

########## Datastore ##########
data "vsphere_host" "host" {
  name          = "esx1"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}
data "vsphere_vmfs_disks" "available" {
  host_system_id = data.vsphere_host.host.id
  rescan         = true
  filter         = "eui.a"
}
data "vsphere_folder" "folder_datastore" {
  path = "/${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.name}/datastore/Projects_Vvols/${var.project_country}"
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name = vsphere_vmfs_datastore.datastore.name
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

datastore.tf:
resource "vsphere_vmfs_datastore" "datastore" {
  name           = "PRO-${var.project_year}-${var.project_country_iso3}-${var.project_type}"
  host_system_id = "${data.vsphere_host.host.id}"
  folder         = data.vsphere_folder.folder_datastore.path
  disks          = data.vsphere_vmfs_disks.available.disks
  depends_on       = [ data.vsphere_vmfs_disks.available ]
}

In my main.tf is the module included. Here are the most important values:
  datastore = local.project_datastore
  vmfolder = local.project_vmfolder_root
  depends_on = [
    vsphere_distributed_port_group.pg,
    data.vsphere_folder.folder_datastore,
    vsphere_vmfs_datastore.datastore,
    vsphere_folder.folder_vm,
    data.vsphere_vmfs_disks.available ]

I would appreciate a lot of help
Thank you in advance.
I already tried to change the dependencies. But unfortunately nothing worked for me. The only thing which worked, was to use an existing VMFS datastore or to deploy the virtual machines with the -target function when I previously deploy the infrastructure.
